# How to move an image independently of each other

Tags: html, css

I made an approximation animation for two images, but I don't know how to move them independently of each other

```
.image {
    width: 200px; 
    height: auto; 
    position: absolute;
}
.image:nth-child(1) {
    top: 50px; 
    left: 500px;
}

.image:nth-child(2) {
    top: 100px;
    left: 200px; 
}
```

I wanted to do this but it doesn't work
I want to use without javascript

Comment: Try adding ```position: absolute;``` to the children.

Comment: you may want to use Javascript for the animation along with your CSS. Using Javascript gives you more control. Tell me if you want pure CSS or you consider using JS.

Comment: Add html and css code snippet to more clariy thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.image-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px; /* Adjust as needed */
    height: 400px; /* Adjust as needed */
}

.image {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px; /* Adjust as needed */
    height: 100px; /* Adjust as needed */
    animation-duration: 4s; /* Animation duration in seconds */
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out; /* Timing function for smooth animation */
    animation-iteration-count: infinite; /* Infinite animation loop */
}

/* Keyframes for Image 1 */
@keyframes moveImage1 {
    0% {
        transform: translate(0, 0);
    }
    50% {
        transform: translate(200px, 0); /* Adjust the distance and direction */
    }
    100% {
        transform: translate(0, 0);
    }
}

/* Keyframes for Image 2 */
@keyframes moveImage2 {
    0% {
        transform: translate(0, 0);
    }
    50% {
        transform: translate(0, 200px); /* Adjust the distance and direction */
    }
    100% {
        transform: translate(0, 0);
    }
}

/* Apply animations to images */
.image:nth-child(1) {
    animation-name: moveImage1;
}

.image:nth-child(2) {
    animation-name: moveImage2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Image Animation</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="image-container">
        <img class="image" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/19/08/32/rose-729509_640.jpg" alt="Image 1">
        <img class="image" src="https://natureconservancy-h.assetsadobe.com/is/image/content/dam/tnc/nature/en/photos/s/h/shutterstock_1512536354.jpg?crop=0%2C350%2C2664%2C1398&wid=1200&hei=630&scl=2.22" alt="Image 2">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```